# Berry Connection Calculation for a 2-Level System

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematics, calculus, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Suppose we start with a state on the Bloch sphere given by:
$$|\psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\\e^{i\varphi} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\end{pmatrix}$$

The Berry Connection is given as:

$$A=i\langle\psi|\nabla|\psi\rangle$$

I am stuck at taking the spherical form of $\boldsymbol \nabla$ on $|\psi\rangle$ so I can't even move forward.

> How can I evaluate this? Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: My issue is how will the matrix $\nabla|\psi\rangle$ look like?

Comment: All you need to do is to apply the derivatives on the entries in your vector.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187040/gradient-of-a-vector-in-spherical-coordinates/3265762 
So do I end up with a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: No it won't become a $3\times 3$ matrix. However, it will be a vectorial quantity because $\nabla$ is a vectorial operator.

Comment: If I grad a scalar it gives a vector, so shouldn't the grad of a vector gives a matrix? Like it increases the rank of the thing I grad with.

Comment: Sorry I'll really appreciate if I can know how the result will look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is really what the explicit form is of $\nabla|\psi\rangle$. The OP provides an expression for the ket $|\psi\rangle$. The first issue is that this is not formally correct. Although we call it a "state vector," it should not really be represented as a stacked vector. Instead, it still needs to contain kets for the basis elements. If we assume a basis represented by $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, then the state would be better represented in the form:
$$ |\psi\rangle = |0\rangle A(\theta,\phi) + |1\rangle B(\theta,\phi) , $$
where $A$ and $B$ are the coefficients as functions of the coordinates on the Bloch sphere. So the state "vector" is not a vector in the same sense as a three-dimensional vector in space.

Now we are ready to apply the gradient operator. The result would have the form
$$ \nabla|\psi\rangle = |0\rangle \nabla A(\theta,\phi) + |1\rangle \nabla B(\theta,\phi) . $$
The gradients of the two coefficient functions become three-dimensional spatial vectors. The resulting quantity is now a combination of a state vector on the Bloch sphere consisting of spatial vectors due to the gradient operation. So, you can think of it as a spatial vector with internal degrees of freedom associated with the Bloch sphere.

Comment: Alright thank you!